# Creating an array of class type using threads

Tags: python, list, multithreading, class

I created a class with 3 variables and a function.
The function random numbers and actually needs to initialize the variables. And when I try to create a list of 360, of class type and using threads, it gives me an error, that is, I make a loop of 360 threads, each thread calls a function and the data that the function returns must be put into a variable of the class type that it created.
I tried to make a loop that creates 360 threads that initialize a list of the AData class type and then I tried to print the value that goes into the first variable in the list and apparently it fails to create it, how do you solve the problem?

this is the error:

```
    print(aDataList[0].get_at())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'get_at'
```

this is the class:

```
import random as rd
import numpy as np

class AData:

    def __init__(self, at, fr, es):
        self.at = at
        self.fr = fr
        self.es = es

    def getAData(self):
        return self

    def get_at(self):
        return self.at

    @classmethod
    def simulate_punction(cls, p, g):
        
        auxiliary_variable = rd.randint(1, 6)
        return_es_array = np.array([(1.5 * auxiliary_variable), 112.5, 150, 67.5,75, 90])
        at = rd.uniform((1/1435)*2, (100 / 1435) * 2)
        at = round(at, 2)
        fr = rd.uniform(0.008, g)
        es = rd.choice(return_es_array)
        return at, fr, es
```

This is the second class:

```
from threading import Thread
from aData import AData

class SW:
    aDataList = []

    for _ in range(360):
        th = Thread(target=AData.simulate_punction, args=(150,), kwargs= {'g': 0.01})
        aDataList.append(th)
        th.start()

    for thread in aDataList:
        thread.join()

    print(aDataList[0].get_at())
```

And do I need to synchronize the access of threads to create a list?

Comment: `aDataList` contains `Thread` instances, not `AData` instances.  In fact, no `AData` instances are ever created since you are calling a class method, so you can't call the instance method `get_at`.

Comment: So how can I see the data inside the objects in the list that the threads created?

Comment: It appears you want to call the function 360 times.  Threading won't help due to the Python GIL (global interpreter lock) only allowing 1 thread of Python code to run at a time.  Multiprocessing could help, but for a short function the overhead is too expensive.  A normal function (remove `cls`) and `results = [simulate_punction(150, .01) for _ in range(360)]` should be sufficient.